# Overlapping text on awaiting redaction approval

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, revision-redaction

There is small text overlapping on the redaction approval page on the moderator pages:

> [image: screenshot of the bug]

This is most likely happening due to the length of the translation (comment -> комментарий).